# Automatic generate data in table when migrate in Django

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration

Im having trouble how to migrate data with value in Django is there any way how can I add automatically data in tables when using command migrations in Django? Let say I have *usertype_tbl* every time I use command makemigrations in Django it should store automatically this data - Admin, Super admin, other_user etc.  in usertype_tbl. Is there any way how to implement this? or any solution and ideas aside from migrations please help me ,thanks for the help in advance!

> models.py

```
class usertypes_tbl(models.Model):
  user_type = models.CharField(max_length=264)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=264)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    //add some data = Admin, Super_admin , etc.
```

Comment: Is there anyway how to do this? I been searching nothing finds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try fixtures in your project try to implement fixture in your project to add the data in you database .